# DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL In React App

Tags: reactjs, rest, axios, nestjs

I'm facing with a mysterious error. When I'm trying to send one specific query to the server, I'm receiving the following error

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL
at dispatchXhrRequest (http://localhost:6789/static/js/20.chunk.js:180790:13)
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at xhrAdapter (http://localhost:6789/static/js/20.chunk.js:180773:10)
at dispatchRequest (http://localhost:6789/static/js/20.chunk.js:181396:10)
```

And here I logged the actual url string

```
http://localhost:3000​/users​/5​/payments​/disconnect
```

If I send the same query but from my hosting to dev server, I see error 404 and url like this

```
https://example.com/users%E2%80%8B/5%E2%80%8B/payments%E2%80%8B/disconnect
```

This is my function which sends the query

```
  const query = `${url}​/users​/${userId}​/payments​/disconnect`;

  console.debug('Url', query);

  try {
    const { status } = await axios.delete(query);
    return status;
  } catch (e) {
    console.debug(e);
    return 500;
  }
}
```

Interesting thing, all other endpoints work fine. The same behavior on chrome and firefox.

What can cause problems like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%E2%80%8B` is a [U+200B : ZERO WIDTH SPACE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) which you've somehow managed to pollute your string with.

You can see them in your source code if you copy/paste the `` const query = `${url}​/users​/${userId}​/payments​/disconnect`; `` line into [this app](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html?).

It is probably most easily removed by editing that line like this:

1. Position the cursor after the character **after** the `/`
2. Press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> until the character **before** the `/` is deleted
3. Retype the three characters you desire

Comment: It works. Thank you a lot! Then I don't understand, how does this character could appeare in the code?

Comment: @IvanBanha — Most likely: It was typed or copy/pasted.

Comment: Wow, hard to believe but this actually was my problem. I had two invisible double byte characters (U+200B : ZERO WIDTH SPACE [ZWSP]) in my URL string. Thank you @Quentin